# Android overridePendingTransition() not working

Tags: java, android, animation, android-activity

I am trying to animate the transition between two Activities with a simple *fade animation*.

When I use the standard android animations it works fine, but when I define my own animations, despite them being the exact same thing, it does not work and i don't see a transition.

*Working code*

**Method call**

```
((Activity) context).overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
```

**Android animation** (fade_in.xml)

```
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@interpolator/decelerate_quad"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" />
```

---

*Non working code*

**Method call**

```
((Activity) context).overridePendingTransition(R.anim.activity_fade_in, R.anim.activity_fade_out);
```

**Custom animation** (res/anim/activity_fade_in.xml)

```
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:duration="500"
   android:fromAlpha="0.0"
   android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/decelerate_quad"
   android:toAlpha="1.0"/>
```

Comment: what´s the value of config_longAnimTime?

Comment: It is defined as 500 in the config like this `<integer name="config_longAnimTime">500</integer>`

Comment: I guess you are missing something in the code. Sometomies an issue is made in the code which is overseen. Please show us the whole part where you call this (with the start next activity part) and how is your folder structure in your project? where ist the animation stored?

Comment: This is being called right after `startActivityForResult()` and the animations are stored in `res/anim/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, unplugging my test device and coming back an hour later seems to have resolved the issue. I'm not quite sure what happened but everything seems to be working properly now.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code this way

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/bounce_interpolator" >
      <alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:duration="500"
            android:fromAlpha="0.0"
            android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/decelerate_quad"
            android:toAlpha="1.0"/>
</set>
```